# Building Kotlin Multiplatform Libraries

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to build multiple Kotlin Multiplatform libraries. I have a good deal of common code we use in our internal "SDK". I have refactored that to the KMP library structure with the common, android, and desktop.

I now am trying to extend the common code in another library that is pulling in the "SDK" project. The IDE cannot find import any of the classes in the "SDK" common folder in the next library common folder, however, it can find them in the android folder of that library.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is my publishing wrong?

The platforms I am compiling to are Desktop, Android and Common. I am using IntelliJ 2022.1.4, Kotlin 1.7.10, Compose Version : 1.2. latest Alpha.

I am using the maven publish plugin and the artifacts are going to JFrog they are being pulled down correctly, but I noticed that the commonMain only has some meta data in it.

Comment: It's hard to know without any specifics. What are the error messages? What build tools are you using? Does it happen only on one machine, or multiple? How are you publishing it? How is it being consumed?

Comment: did you tried to build artifact and use it without maven? something like "jsBrowserDevelopmentLibraryDistribution" and link it manually?